# Intersection of inverse projection of product topologies is subbasis but not basis why?

Tags: general-topology

I am reading *James R. Mukres Topology*. In that Theorem 15.2 which states that,

$$S = \{\pi_1^{-1}(U) | U \text{ open in X } \} \cup \{ \pi_2^{-1}(V) | V \text{ open in Y } \} $$ 
then $S$ is a subbasis

First, the $\cup$ should have been $\cap$

But my question is more around, it should really be basis too right? Since for every $B$ in basis of $U$ and $B^`$ in basis of $V$ means $B \times B^`$ should be in $S$ too right? I don't quite understand why we need finite intersections to get them. Am i missing something here?

Comment: No, it must be $\cup$. You may have the wrong picture in mind. The given subbasis is $\{ U \times Y : U \text{ open in } X\} \cup \{ X \times V : V \text{ open in } Y\}$. You may have thought of the family $\{ \pi_1^{-1}(U) \cap \pi_2^{-1}(V) : U \text{ open in } X \land V \text{ open in } Y\}$.

Comment: Oh, i get the difference. But still i don't understand why its not a basis? Also $\{U \times Y : U \text{ open in } X \}$ should be equal to $\{X \times V : V \text{ open in } Y\}$, unless $X$ or $Y$ is empty (even then they are equal trivially)

Comment: Sorry i got it why its not basis thanks

Comment: It is only a basis of the product topology if one of the spaces carries the indiscrete (perhaps Munkres uses "trivial") topology. If $\varnothing \neq U_0 \neq X$ is open, and $\varnothing \neq V_0 \neq Y$ is open, then $U_0\times V_0$ is an open set that is not a union of sets of the form $U\times Y$ or $X\times V$.

Answer (score 0):

No, we do need union. We need all sets that are either of the form $\pi_1^{-1}[U]$ for $U$ open in $X$ **or** of the form $\pi_2^{-1}[V]$ where $V$ is open in $Y$. So we have a union of two families of sets, of specific forms.

It's not a base because if we take a set from the left side, say $\pi_1^{-1}[U_0]$ and one from the right $\pi_2^{-1}[V_0]$, and we have a point $(x_0, y_0)$ in their intersection, which is $U_0 \times V_0$, then no set of the form $\pi_1^{-1}[U]$ that contains $(X_0,y_0)$ can be a subset of $U_0 \times V_0$ (this is a condition for being a base!), if $V_0 \neq Y$, because if we pick $q \in Y \notin V_0$, then $(x_0,q) \in pi_1^{-1}[U]$ but is not in $U_0 \times V_0$, and similarly for sets of the other form if $U_0 \neq X$, use $p \in X \setminus U_0$ we reason similarly on $(p,y_0)$.

In simpler terms (more pictorial): sets of either form always stick out of the smaller box $U_0 \times V_0$ that forms their intersection.